# How to fix "using uninitialized memory" in C

Tags: c

Writing a program when learning sequential list, now I want to achieve a search function, but it keeps telling me "List" and "books_info" are using uninitialized memory.

I'm confused: I already defined that in my main function.

```c
typedef struct {
    char ISBN[14];
    char name[MAXSIZE];
    float price;
} Book;

typedef struct {
    Book* elem;
    int length;
} SqList;

// ...

int main() {
    SqList List;
    Book books_info;

// ...

        switch (switch_option) {
        case 3:
            printf("Please input a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &search);

            temp = GetElem(List, search, books_info);

// ...
```

Comment: Did you notice that it says uninitialized and doesn't say undefined?

Comment: @immibis Sorry, I have a function which will initialize a sequential list(and while testing will run that first). But after running that then do this, the program will crash :/

Comment: *What* are "telling" you? The compiler? Some other program? Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us, one that replicates the problem you have. Then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question as well. And include comments on the lines where you get the errors, so we know where they are. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Non-static local variables are not subject to default initialization.  If you do not initialize them explicitly in their declarations then their initial values are indeterminate.  You may assign values later, but until you do so, reading their values produces undefined behavior.